# ColdFusion SessionTracker and forcing the session to end

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using the ColdFusion 9 `coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker` to monitor currently logged in users using the following code.

```
app = application.getApplicationSettings().name;
sessiontracker = createObject("java","coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker");
sessionCollection = sessionTracker.getSessionCollection(app);
```

Which returns a `struct` of `jsessionid`'s and the session's variables for all the currently active sessions.

Is it possible to force a session to end given I have the `jsessionid` effectively forcing the user to be logged out?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason you need to do this? There are a lot of blog entries on ending sessions. Depending on your needs, there may be better options than using an internal class. But to answer your question, dump the SessionTracker object. There is a `cleanUp(appName, sessionID)` method that *might* do this. Though I have never used it myself.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply only just getting back to working on this project. I've dumped the SessionTracker object but there is no `cleanUp(appName, sessionID)` method.

Comment: No, it is there. It is listed as `cleanup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`. The first parameter is the application name and the second the session ID.

Comment: Not sure where your looking, see here for a dump of the `SessionTracker` object. [http://www.linfoots.com/sessionTracker.cfm](http://www.linfoots.com/sessionTracker.cfm) are you running ColdFusion 10?

Comment: Nope, I used the version in your question tags - CF9 ;-) I guess it does not exist in CF10? {shrug} That is the risk of using internal classes. The undocumented functionality may go away without warning.

Comment: Strange, I too am using CF9. I thought you might be using CF10 as you have it and I don't. Thanks for your thoughts anyway.

Comment: Weird, it is there in `9,0,1,274733`. If you do not see it, we must be using different versions and it is not included in yours. That said, I am not big on using using this kind of undocumented functionality outside of development anyway.. for exactly this reason. "Now you see it, now you don't" :)

Comment: @Leigh: it's not there on my 9,0,1,274733 install either. Odd.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Huh... I have since switched machines and I do not see it in the dump now either. So now I am scratching my head too. The weird thing is .. the method is there (really). You can see it if you use reflection or `javap -s ...`.

Comment: I too am unable to see this method on my new server where it was there on my old server.  Now what?

Comment: For any who find this and try to run it in CF10 and above, you may find the first line of code not working. You can use this instead: app = getapplicationmetadata().name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when a user logs in I'm setting a `user` structure in their session, so to remove their logged in state. Using `sessionTracker` I can get a specific user's session and just delete the `user` structure in their current session.

```
app = application.getApplicationSettings().name;
sessiontracker = createObject("java","coldfusion.runtime.SessionTracker");
sessionCollection = sessionTracker.getSessionCollection(app);

userSession = sessiontracker.getSession(app, sessionID));

structDelete(userSession, "user");
```

Not sure if this is the best way of doing it but it seems to work for me. Hope it helps people.

Comment: This worked great when my sites were on Windows 2003.  Now, trying to move them to Windows 2008R2 and the cleanup() method is gone and trying to assign the session to a variable gives me a 500 server error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the onSessionEnd in the application.cfc?  Since we can fire it manually in a logout process or it will fire automatically if the user closes the browser or whatever it works great. This is how we use it.

In the application.cfc we fire the onSessionEnd and it fires the logout function which is also  in the application.cfc and does all of the clean stuff and logging.

```
<cffunction name="OnSessionEnd" access="public" returntype="void"
                 output="false" hint="Fires when the session is terminated.">
        <cfargument name="SessionScope" type="struct" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="ApplicationScope" type="struct"
                                  required="false" default="#StructNew()#" />
        <cfargument name="timedOut" type="boolean" required="false" default="true">
                <cfinvoke thisSessionScope="#SessionScope#"
                      timedOut="#arguments.timedOut#" method="logout">
                </cfinvoke>
            <cfset structClear(arguments.sessionScope) >
         <!--- Return out. --->
        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you take the question literally, he is trying to force the session to end.  OnSessionEnd won't run until that actually happens.  Of course it's possible that there is a difference between what he asked and what he actually wants.

Comment: as in onSessionEnd(the session id he said he had)?  I've never had reason to try.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply only just getting back to working on this project. I've been able to find a way of manually calling the event handler `onSessionEnd()`. However I have found a pretty simple way of invalidating a users login status. See Answer.